# is SHA512 with 256 bits set to zero equivalent to SHA256?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I'm doing my first steps in cryptography.

i'm trying to understand why sha512 with 256 bits set to zero, is not equal to sha256?
there is some similarity between sha512 with 256 bits set to zero and sha256?

Comment: What does "sha512 with 256 bits set to zero" even mean?

Comment: Sorry, for that. SHA(Secure Hash Algorithm), both SHA256 and SHA512 based on SHA. SHA-256 and SHA-512 are novel hash functions computed with eight 32-bit and 64-bit words, respectively

Comment: @ish It's the "with 256 bits set to zero" part that isn't clear

Comment: Sorry again. if I have array of length of 512 bits, if for example 256  bits are set to zero, calculating SHA512, is this case similar to SHA256?

Comment: If this is part of learning cryptography, I highly recommend starting at the standard (https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf) and try implementing it yourself. You'll quickly answer this question. The standards are quite well-written and you should become comfortable reading them. The whole thing, including SHA-1 and all the versions of SHA-2 is only about 30 pages. There are also excellent test vectors, including intermediate steps, so that you can debug your implementations. https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/example-values

Comment: Wikipedia provides a nice summarized version that may help you get your head around the topic, but I do recommend getting used to the NIST website and reading the standards. It's a key skill in this space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2

Comment: The main reason for not the equality is the [domain separation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83306/18298) so that when the two hash functions are deployed on the same/or different site, they don't have the same hash value on the same values. Having different initial values provides this other than the block and round size,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While SHA-512 and SHA-256 have similar structure, they use different block length, internal state size, number of rounds and initial hash values.

Therefore, although the computations are the same, the output is very different, even if you provide similar input (such as 256 zero bits). Additionally the output of SHA-512 is 512 bits whereas SHA-256 provides 256 bits of output; so no, SHA-512 is not the same as SHA-256.